# Getting VS code server to run on Sagemaker Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio, visual-studio-code-server

I am currently in the process of exploring the possible use of VS Code Server on Sagemaker Studio. Of course, if you sign up through Code Server preview, I was able to set and start it up. However, when I tried  to serve it locally, I encountered a blank page after modifying the /default/proxy/XXX part of the url like how we access tensorboard.

Just wondering on whether are there any tinkerers out there that managed to get it working? (and yes, I understand that somebody managed to get it running https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest/CONTRIBUTING. but wondering whether anybody managed to use the native installation to work properly? Any possible steps that i may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the blog post here for hosting code-server on SageMaker Studio - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/host-code-server-on-amazon-sagemaker/

And associated git repo here - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-codeserver